# Karate: one liner json path expression not working

Tags: karate

I have a two line json path expression that prints something and I want to put it all in one line:

```
Given path 'device/'
When method get
Then status 200

#This correctly prints the value:
And def device_search = $.device[?(@.manufacturer == 'a manufacturer')]
And print device_search[0].id

#This doesn't work (prints null):
And print $.device[?(@.manufacturer == 'a manufacturer')][0].id
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$.device[?(@.manufacturer == 'a manufacturer')].id[0]`

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but without success (null)

Comment: @italktothewind lol. you really do need to find a magician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Use 2 steps.

But if you insist, use `karate.get()`.

```
And print karate.get("$.device[?(@.manufacturer == 'a manufacturer')][0].id")
```